# MS Word 2016 Figure caption numbering - want to be able to be to have decimal ie Figure 7.2

Tags: microsoft-word, caption

I'm trying to create custom image caption numbers for figures in a report in MS Word 2016 professional. I would like to be able to have "Figure 6. description of image" and then "Figure 6.1. description of image". The report is NOT broken into chapters.

I've tried using References > Insert Caption, which works until I need to use a decimal number. I've tried to work around this by using Crtl+F9 to insert a blank field and enter {SEQ Figure * ARABIC \n 6.1} (this is how the captions generate from Reference > Insert Caption) and it simply doesn't show the number when I toggle back to plain text. I tried using the \r n switch with 6.1, same result. Tried ... \r n6}.1 and same result - thought maybe this would just restart my numbering at 6 and the .1 would be plain text in the following description but look alright in the finished report. Is there anyway to get the numbering the way I want?

Answer (score 0):

### Use Chapter Numbering in your Captions

This is covered in my [page on Complex Documents](https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/complex_documents.htm#Caption).

> **Chapter Numbering for Captions**
>
> You can use chapter numbering in captions. To do this, your chapters
> must start with a style set for numbering. See [How to create numbered](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)
> [headings or outline numbering in Ribbon Versions of Word by Shauna](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html)
> [Kelly](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html) for instructions on doing that. You click on the Numbering
> button in the Insert Caption dialog and tell Word which style has your
> numbering. You can choose the style which designates the beginning of
> your chapter in the Caption Numbering dialog. Numbering of captions
> will restart with each chapter.
>
> [image: screenshot]
>
> If you choose to include the Chapter number in your caption,
> numbering will restart with each chapter. While you can have the
> chapter number without restarting, you can't do that through the
> dialog box. You would need to modify the SEQ field to remove the \s
> switch at the end.
>
> Here is a Table caption with field display toggled. It is as set by
> the dialog box with a chapter number included:
>
> [image: screenshot of field code]
>
> Here is the same caption after being modified to remove the restart
> switch at the end of the SEQ field:
>
> [image: screenshot of modified field code]

The shots above show a dash or hyphen separator but you could use a decimal point / period instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, some observations on the "problem side" of what you are doing.

A single SEQ field only really allows 'whole number' numbering. There is no way you can tell a **single** SEQ field to start numbering at `6.1`, carry on to `6.2`, and so on.

So if you need numbering like `6.1`, `6.2`, `6.3`, you either have to insert and maintain the numbers manually or work out a numbering scheme (probably using `SEQ` fields) that works.

But creating your own scheme introduces a whole bunch of problems. Caption numbering is one of those things in Word that works reasonably well if you do it the way Word expects you to do it. If you don't, you may find, for example, that

- Word will omit some captions when you try to use its standard Table of Figures feature
- Word will not present all of your Figure captions in the Cross-reference dialog box when you select the *Reference Type* **Figure**
- The cross-reference dialog box will not create cross-references to the complete figure number
- You have to use different field coding for different captions, which means that if you resequence your Figures, you have to modify your fields by hand, which means you don't really benefit from the automation that `{ SEQ }` fields provide.

In other words, if you possibly can stick to a scheme where you just number Figures sequentially `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, with no `6.1` etc., I would do so.

Second, an observation on Word's "Chapter numbering". ALthough Word talks about "Chapter numbers" in its Caption numbering dialog, it's not really referring to any Chapter organisation you may have in your document. It's just saying

- If you want a two-part Caption number such as `1-1`, `1-2`, `1-3` etc. then
- select a built-in `Heading` style (`Heading 1` to `Heading 9`) that uses automatic heading numbering. Let's say you choose `Heading 5`
- Word will use the numbering in the most recent `Heading 5` paragraph as the first part of the Caption number
- Word will reset the second part of the Caption Number to `1` (or `A`, etc.) after each `Heading 5` paragraph.

In other words, the heading number you choose doesn't have to have anything to do with any Chapter organisation you might or might not have in your document. But you would need to have *some* automatic numbering in a heading to get your `6.1`, `6.2` numbering.

But let's say you can't do that.

In my view there are at least three schemes you might be trying to number your captions.

- Scheme 1: every Figure has a two-part number, e.g.

  1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.1, 2.2, 3.1, 4.1, 4.2 etc.
- Scheme 2: the first figure with a given number has a one-part number, and subsequent ones have a 2-part number, e.g.

  1, 1.1, 1.2, 2, 3, 4, 4.1, 4.2 etc.
- Scheme 3: any number N either has a single caption numbered N, or multiple captions numbered N.1, N.2, N.3 etc., e.g.

  1.1, 1.2, 2, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 4, 5, 6.1, 6.2 etc.

So how do we do those? Well, there are some constraints on how you do it.

Word's standard Table of Figures ToC, which uses this field coding

```
{ TOC \h \z \c "Figure" }
```

will only list paragraphs that contain a `{ SEQ Figure }` code. Word's cross-reference dialog will also only list those paragraphs when you choose *Reference type* **Figure**.

The most obvious way to achieve `Scheme 1` numbering using `SEQ` fields is this

```
{ SEQ Figure }.{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }
```

for `1.1`, `2.1`, `3.1` etc. and

```
{ SEQ Figure \c }.{ SEQ Subfigure }
```

for all the other Figure captions. In all cases, *all* the `{ }` need to be the special field code brace pairs that you can insert on Windows desktop Word using Ctrl-F9 or similar.

*But* Word does not actually pick up captions that contain `{ SEQ Figure \c }` (or the hidden `{ SEQ Figure \h }`) in either the Table of Figures or the cross-reference dialog.

You could use a different ToC field. I'll cover that later.

But you can make this work by saving the Figure sequence number and re-using it as follows:

```
{ SEQ Figure }.{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }{ SET SFigure { SEQ Figure \c } }
```

for `1.1`, `2.1` etc. and

```
{ SEQ Figure \r{ SFigure } }.{ SEQ Subfigure }
```

for all the others. Word picks up `{ SEQ Figure \r x }` captions in the Table of Figures and cross-reference dialog.

But there is still one problem with the cross-referencing dialog.

It will work fine if you select **Entire Caption** in the *Insert reference to:* dropdown. But if you select **Only Label and Number**, Word only references the caption to the end of the `{ SEQ Figure }` field.

So if your caption says

```
Figure 1.1 A reCaptcha dialog
```

Word will only insert the cross-reference text

```
Figure 1
```

Similarly, if you select **Only Caption Text**, word will insert the text after the `{ SEQ Figure }` field (and will also omit the following ".")

```
1 A reCaptcha dialog
```

which almost certainly isn't what you want.

We can fix that by making sure that the `{ SEQ }` field generates the entire reference *number* using a numeric format, like this:

```
{ SEQ Figure \#"0'.{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }'" }{ SET SFigure { SEQ Figure \c } }
```

for the `1.1`, `2.1`, `3.1` captions and

```
{ SEQ Figure \r{ SFigure } \#"0'.{ SEQ Subfigure }'" }
```

for all the others.

Let's just go through the explanation.

```
 { SEQ Figure \#"0'.{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }'" }{ SET SFigure { SEQ Figure \c } }
```

says

- Insert the next number in the Figure sequence, formatted using 0'{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }'. In the format,

  - 0 is a placeholder that will be replaced by the current value of the Figure sequence. We only need one 0, even for sequence numbers 10 and above.
  - `'.{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }'` inserts the literal text @.@ followed by the value of `{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }`
  - `{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }` sets the Subfigure sequence to 1 and displays `1`
- Then set the value of bookmark `SFigure` to the current value of the Figure sequence (i.e. the one we just displayed).

Then

```
{ SEQ Figure \r{ SFigure } \#"0'.{ SEQ Subfigure }'" }
```

says

- Set the value of the `Figure` sequence to the value of `SFigure` and insert that number formatted using `0'.{ SEQ SubFigure }'`

This is all rather complicated (as suggested earlier!) but you can make it a bit simpler by setting up autotexts/autocorrects to insert each sequence.

Just remember that if you resequence, you may have to modify the existing coding or remove it and re-insert it.

Now let's do something similar for `Scheme 2`:

For `1`, `2`, `3` we can use

```
{ SEQ Figure }{ SET SFigure { SEQ Figure \c } }{ SEQ Subfigure \r0 \h }
```

For all the rest we can use the same coding as above, i.e.

```
{ SEQ Figure \r{ SFigure } \#"0'.{ SEQ Subfigure }'" }
```

`Scheme 3` is a bit harder because we need three different sequences.

For `1`, `2`, `3` we can use the simple

```
{ SEQ Figure }
```

For `4.1`, `5.1` etc. we can use the same coding as in `Scheme 1`, i.e.

```
{ SEQ Figure \#"0'.{ SEQ Subfigure \r1 }'" }{ SET SFigure { SEQ Figure \c } }
```

and for all the rest we also use the `Scheme 1` coding, i.e.

```
{ SEQ Figure \r{ SFigure } \#"0'.{ SEQ Subfigure }'" }
```

That's the end of all that complicated stuff. It's only really there to enable the use of the standard Table of Figures TOCs and standard cross-referencing. If you don't need all that and you don't mind maintaining your sequences and any cross-references manually, you could reduce the complexity a lot (e.g. not use any SEQ fields at all).

Specifically, for a Table of Figures, instead of using

```
{ TOC \h \z \c "Figure" }
```

you could apply a paragraph style to all your Figure captions (let's call it `FigureStyle`) and use

```
{ TOC \h \z \t "FigureStyle,1" }
```

to pick up all the text. (If your Windows settings have the list separator character set to ";" you'll need

```
{ TOC \h \z \t "FigureStyle;1" }
```

instead).

Finally, why the things you tried didn't work:-

`{ SEQ Figure \* Arabic \n 6.1 }` doesn't work because `\n` just uses the next number (e.g. if the current Figure is 6 the next one is 7. `\n` doesn't let you *specify* the next number, just use it.)

Using `\r` to specify the starting number doesn't work with a number like `6.1` because Word only recognises the first whole number it encounters in the text following the `\r` - in this case, it will ignore everything from the "." onwards.